# Perform the following 1's complement fixed-point integer arithmetic operations

Tags: math, logic

This question is from my digital logic class but I don't understand it. Please help me understand what it is asking me.

Lets say A1 and A2 are octal shorthand.

> Perform the following 1's complement fixed-point integer arithmetic operations and note whether magnitude overflow has occurred in each case: (Hint: Use 7's complement arithmetic on the other octal shorthand),

```
i) A3= A1+A2
ii) A3= A1-A2
```

I thought you only take complements when you want to do subtraction. Can't I just do the subtraction in octal form? Can someone help me understand what the questions are ask?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick question; or you misquoted it. I doubt your instructor would ask the former; so it must be the latter.

Recall that a 1s complement sum is the XOR of two operands (here A1 and A2). And that there is no carry and therefore no such thing as magnitude overflow in the 1s complement world.

Comment: I copied it exactly so it must be a trick question. When he say 1's complement does that mean I have invert the 1's and 0's of A1 and A1 binary, then add them up? What is with the Hint, saying to use 7's complement?

Comment: Forget about the notion of algebraic "add" in 1s complement. 1s complement "add" of two operands is exactly "operand1 XOR operand2."  I have no idea what he means by "7s complement." Maybe it has something to with octal, but to me it doesn't make sense. I suppose there exists a "7s complement" representation but I have to believe that's a typo for "2s complement."

Comment: A1 and A2 are not octal numbers, which are in the range 0-7. If they are hex, then possible octal representations are A1: 0241; A2: 0242. But even that doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the obscure "octal short-hand"/"7s-complement" comes into play, but here is the "traditional" solution:

```
i) A3 = A1+A2
       1
       2631
       84268421
       01000000
    A1=10100001 = -94
  + A2=10100010 = -93
    ------------
    A3=01000011 = -187 < -127 so we know this is wrong 
co:    10100000

  CO = 1 which also indicates result is wrong


ii) A3 = A1-A2
        1000000
    A1=10100001 = -33
  - A2=10100010 = -34
    ------------
    A3=????????? =  1  < 127 so we know this is right
  ==
        0000010
    A1=10100001
  + A2=01011101
    ------------
    A3=11111110 = -67
co:    00000001 = 1

  CO = 0 which also indicates result is right
```